# What would be the appropriate model association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I have an Organization and Actioncode model. When signing up for a premium account, an organization can enter an actioncode for a discount. Hence, an organization has used no or 1 actioncode, while an actioncode can be used by many organizations.

**Current association:**

```
Organizations migration file:  t.references :actioncode,   index: true,    foreign_key: true
Organization model:            belongs_to :actioncode
Actioncode model:              has_many :organizations
```

**Initial problem with this setup: actioncode_id should not be mandatory** On seeding I used to get the error code `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Actioncode(#23575660) expected, got Fixnum(#5494220)`. The cause seemed to be that actioncode_id had become a mandatory column in the Organization model. This should not be the case; actioncode should also be able to be `nil` as an organization may also *not* use/have any actioncode when paying for a premium account.

**Current situation: After upgrading to PostgreSQL:** In response I've upgraded my db to PostgreSQL. Nevertheless, now on migration I get the error message (see full message at bottom of post):

> PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "actioncodes" does not exist

**The error message:** Any ideas what is causing this error? Removing the three lines under 'current association' and I have no problems with migration and seeding. In fact, keeping all three lines but removing `index: true, foreign_key: true` from the first line and it also migrates correctly. When I keep `index: true` on migration it gives the error: `SyntaxError: xxx_create_organizations.rb:17: syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting => t.boolean :activated`. When I keep `foreign_key: true` it produces the original error message `PG::UndefinedTable`.

And if I change the first line to the incorrect code of: `t.references :actioncode_id, index: true, foreign_key: true` it gives as the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "actioncode_ids" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "organizations" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_604f95d1a1"
FOREIGN KEY ("actioncode_id_id")
  REFERENCES "actioncode_ids" ("id")
```

So given _ids on the last line, Rails somehow does seem to have problems with the name of the table. Adding `self.table_name = 'actioncodes'` to the actioncode model file makes no difference. What to do?

---

*Alternative associations:*

I wonder if I need an alternative association to meet my need. I've looked into several other associations but am unsure what to do. Best case scenario I just have a column in the organization model that includes the used actioncode or is nil if no actioncode was used. I need a model association to for example print all the organizations that have used a specific actioncode.

**Alternative association 1:** Problem with this association is that actioncode remains a mandatory variable in the organization model and thus cannot be nil.

```
Organization migration:  t.references :actioncode,   index: true,    foreign_key: true
Organization model:      has_one :actioncode
Actioncode model:        has_many :organizations
```

**Alternative association 2:** This association would hold the organization_id in the actioncodes table (I guess as an array), while from my perspective it would make much more sense to include the actioncode_id in the organization table. Also, the code below still expects an actioncode for each organization.

```
Organization model:          has_one :actioncode
Actioncodes migration file:  t.belongs_to :organization, index: true
```

**Alternative association 3:** I've also looked at creating an additional association model but it makes me wonder if I'm not overthinking things when I would follow this strategy, as this would add an extra table/model. Also, I'm unsure if the organization model below wouldn't still require a value for discount, thereby not really solving the original problem. But if this would be the way to go, I was thinking of:

```
Organization model:    has_one :discount
                       has_one :actioncode, through: :discount
Discount model:        belongs_to :organization
                       has_one :actioncode
Actioncode model:      belongs_to :discount
Discount migration:    t.belongs_to :organization, index: true
                       doesn;t need any other columns
Actioncode migration:  t.belongs_to :discount, index: true
```

**Alternative association 4:** Lastly, the has_and_belongs_to_many Association didn't make sense to me since how I understand it that's intended for a many:many relationship, while organization:actioncode is a many:1/0 relationship.

**What setup should I use and doesn't have actioncode as a mandatory variable for an organization?**

---

**Additional information:** The SQL from running `rake db:migrate` after `rake db:drop` and `rake db:create`):

```
== 20150410153815 CreateUsers: migrating ===============================
-- create_table(:users)
   -> 0.0582s
== 20150410153815 CreateUsers: migrated (0.0628s) ======================

== 20150410200022 AddIndexToUsersEmailAndUsername: migrating ===========
-- add_index(:users, :email, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0109s
-- add_index(:users, :username, {:unique=>true})
   -> 0.0100s
== 20150410200022 AddIndexToUsersEmailAndUsername: migrated (0.0219s) ==

== 20150416113853 CreateOrganizations: migrating ==============================
-- create_table(:organizations)
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "actioncodes" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "organizations" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_4ecaa2493e"
FOREIGN KEY ("actioncode_id")
  REFERENCES "actioncodes" ("id")
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
<<SNIP>>
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "actioncodes" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "organizations" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_4ecaa2493e"
FOREIGN KEY ("actioncode_id")
  REFERENCES "actioncodes" ("id")
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `async_exec'
<<SNIP>>
```

**Additional information:** The SQL from the migration running the current association (running `rake db:drop` and then `rake db:setup`):

```
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.0664s
-- create_table("actioncodes", {:force=>:cascade})
   -> 0.0412s
-- add_index("actioncodes", ["actioncode"], {:name=>"index_actioncodes_on_actioncode", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0217s
-- create_table("organizations", {:force=>:cascade})
   -> 0.0237s
-- add_index("organizations", ["summ"], {:name=>"index_organizations_on_summ", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0106s
-- add_index("organizations", ["name"], {:name=>"index_organizations_on_name", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0197s
<<SNIP, OTHER TABLES >>
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0352s
-- enable_extension("plpgsql")
   -> 0.0405s
-- create_table("actioncodes", {:force=>:cascade})
   -> 0.0176s
-- add_index("actioncodes", ["actioncode"], {:name=>"index_actioncodes_on_actioncode", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0085s
-- create_table("organizations", {:force=>:cascade})
   -> 0.0148s
-- add_index("organizations", ["summ"], {:name=>"index_organizations_on_summ", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0113s
-- add_index("organizations", ["name"], {:name=>"index_organizations_on_name", :unique=>true, :using=>:btree})
   -> 0.0195s
<<SNIP, OTHER TABLES >>
-- initialize_schema_migrations_table()
   -> 0.0342s
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Actioncode(#39911240) expected, got Fixnum(#20092360)
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/association.rb:216:in `raise_on_type_mismatch!'
<<SNIP >>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on, "... an organization has no or 1 actioncode and an actioncode can be used by many organizations", your modelling is correct, it's just that the foreign key that has been created by the migration does not allow nulls in the actioncode_id column. You might check the migration SQL to see what command is used.

Maybe the database you're using doesn't allow nil foreign key columns, but most do. You might have to construct the foreign key with SQL instead of with Rails in order to allow nulls.

From the postgresql docs: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/ddl-constraints.html

> Now it is impossible to create orders with non-NULL product_no entries that do not appear in the products table.

Note, "... with non-NULL product_no entries ...", null entries should be fine, and your modelling is correct.

Comment: Thanks, so I think I should first upgrade to PostgreSQL to test if it then works. I was already using it in production but SQLite in development. I'll post back once I have upgraded (so far without success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30233999/postgresql-could-not-connect-to-server-connection-timed-out)

Comment: Yes, you should definitely use the same DB for development and production.

Comment: I've upgraded to PostgreSQL. I used `rake db:drop` and then `rake db:setup` with the three lines at the beginning of the original post included in the code. Unfortunately, on seeding I still get the same error message.

Comment: Can you show the SQL that the migration used to create the table and add the foreign key

Comment: I've added the SQL of the migration to the original post. I left out the SQL for the other tables (included actioncode and organization).

Comment: I also added information in that when I keep the three lines in the migration file but leave out `index: true, foreign_key: true` in the first line, that it does migrate without errors. I don't understand what could be causing the error message. I don't belief I have deferred anywhere from naming conventions.

Comment: It turned out that the migration order was the problem. It migrated Organizations before Actionmodels. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290250/pgundefinedtable-error-relation-does-not-exist

Comment: Good news. Funny how these things can throw you down the wrong path.

Answer (score 1):

You have a logic/flow problem here.

`Organization` shouldn't belong to `Actioncode`, if anything an `Organization` can **own** one code. Or not. That's why

Organization

```
has_one :actioncode
```

Actioncode

```
belongs_to :organization
```

That way `Organization` won't hold the `actioncode_id`, but `Actioncode` will hold `organization_id`.

**UPDATE**:

Do as I mentioned above and make `Actioncode` posess a `type` or `value` field which would contain a `'AC-08821'` string for example. That way you could maintain the relations expected between those two models and still be able to e.g. search for all codes with the same `value`.

**OR**

Create an association table, for example using `has_and_belongs_to_many`

More info here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many

Basically you create another table which represents a connection between the two models.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. What would this mean for the migration files? How should these need to be changed? Because also with `has_one :actioncode`, `belongs_to :organization`, and the `t.references` line in the migration file, it still expects an actioncode_id in the organization table.

Comment: I also wonder that if you use `belongs_to :organization` for actioncode, an actioncode could only be used by 1 organization instead of many organizations using that same actioncode.   At guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association I read "such that each instance of the declaring model "belongs to" one instance of the other model".

Comment: `organizations` table will no longer have the `actioncode_id` column so you need to remove that reference from it, but instead each `Actioncode` will point to the `Organization` it **belongs_to**, so you need to add the reference to `:organization` in your `Actioncode` migration (or create another migration that makes those changes)

Comment: I tried `t.belongs_to :organization, index: true` in the actioncodes migration file (I tried it with and without including `foreign_key: true`), and `has_one :actioncode` in the organization model file. When I try to seed this still produces the error `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch: Actioncode(#36377580) expected, got Fixnum(#6043080)`. So it still seems to expect an actioncode for each organization.

Comment: If creating an additional association model would be the way to go, would the setup mentioned in the update be correct?