# Rails: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "..." does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-migrations

On migration I get the following error message:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "actioncodes" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "organizations" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_4ecaa2493e"
FOREIGN KEY ("actioncode_id")
  REFERENCES "actioncodes" ("id")
```

I have the following migration file for Organizations:

```
class CreateOrganizations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :organizations do |t|
      t.string     :name,         null: false,    limit: 40
      t.references :actioncode,   index: true,    foreign_key: true
      t.boolean    :activated
      t.datetime   :activated_at

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And for Actioncodes I have the migration file:

```
class CreateActioncodes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :actioncodes do |t|
      t.string  :code,          null: false,  limit: 20
      t.string  :description,                 limit: 255

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
class AddIndexToActioncodesCode < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_index :actioncodes, :code,  unique: true
  end
end
```

The organization model file includes: `belongs_to :actioncode`.

While the actioncodes model file includes: `has_many :organizations`.

**Any idea what could be causing the error message?**

If I remove `index: true, foreign_key: true` from the migration file, it migrates without errors. And when I replace that line with the incorrect line `t.references :actioncode_id, index: true, foreign_key: true`, it gives the error below, where the last line ("ids") suggests Rails somehow seems to have problem with the name of the table?

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "actioncode_ids" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "organizations" ADD CONSTRAINT "fk_rails_604f95d1a1"
FOREIGN KEY ("actioncode_id_id")
  REFERENCES "actioncode_ids" ("id")
```

Comment: The table name is actioncodes. I've added its migration file to the original post

Comment: Looks like the `CreateOrganizations` migration is being run before  `CreateActioncodes` is executed.  - `CreateActioncodes`  is to be run first thereby ensuring that the `actioncodes` table exists.

Comment: Can you perhaps advice how I should change this? I checked and the SQL code indeed confirms Organizations is being created before Actioncodes is.

Comment: I think what I need is an additional/new migration file that creates the reference: `t.references :actioncode,   index: true,    foreign_key: true`. And then manually remove that line from the current organizations migration file. But what would the command be to create the additional/new migration file?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

So the issue is happening because `CreateOrganizations` migration is being run before `CreateActioncodes` is executed.

`CreateActioncodes` is to be run first thereby ensuring that the `action codes` table exists.

The order in which migrations are run is based on the time stamp of the migration - as indicated in the name of the file. `20141014183645_create_users.rb` will run before `20141014205756_add_index_to_users_email.rb` as the timestamp of the second one - `20141014205756` is after that of the first one - `20141014183645`.

Make sure the time-stamps of the `CreateOrganizations` migration is after that of `CreateActioncodes` migration.

Either you could manually change the timestamp in the file names. Or delete these migration files, and create them in the correct order.

Comment: This worked! I used `rails generate migration AddActioncodeToOrganizations actioncode:references` to create a new migration file for the reference. Removed the reference from old migration file (which I kept for the other variables). 
The answer from @mu is too short is of course also right, but @Prakesh was just a bit earlier, so I've accepted this as the solution.

Comment: Thanks - something easily overlooked when generating db models

Comment: 2022 still works well

Answer (score 10):

The `foreign_key: true` in this line:

```
t.references :actioncode,   index: true,    foreign_key: true
```

tells Rails to create a foreign key inside the database. A [foreign key](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK):

> constraint specifies that the values in a column (or a group of columns) must match the values appearing in some row of another table. We say this maintains the *referential integrity* between two related tables.

So it is some logic inside the database (where it belongs) that ensures you can't put invalid values in your `actioncode` column and that you can't remove entries from the `actioncodes` table that are being used elsewhere.

In order to create the constraint, the referenced table (`actioncodes`) needs to exist before you refer to it. Looks like your migrations are trying to create `organizations` before `actioncodes` so all you need to do is rename the `CreateOrganizations` migration file so that its timestamp prefix comes after the one for `CreateActioncodes`. The prefix is just a timestamp in the format YYYYMMDDhhmmss so change the `CreateOrganizations` timestamp to the `CreateActioncodes` timestamp with one more second.

Answer (score 6):

I was also getting this error. If you are using a test database to run rspec make sure you run `rake db:test:prepare` in the terminal before running rspec.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same challenge when working on a Rails 6 application in Ubuntu 20.04.

I am working on a College Portal where I have model called `School` and another called `Program`. The model `Program` belongs to the model `School`, so it is required that I add a `school` references column to the `programs` table.

I used this command this create the migration file:

```
rails generate model School name:string logo:json motto:text address:text

rails generate model Program name:string logo:json motto:text school_id:references
```

However, when I run the command: `rails db:migrate`

I was getting the error:

```
== 20201208043945 CreateSchools: migrating ====================================
-- create_table(:schools)
   -> 0.0140s
== 20201208043945 CreateSchools: migrated (0.0141s) ===========================

== 20201208043958 CreatePrograms: migrating ===================================
-- create_table(:programs)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  relation "school_ids" does not exist
```

**Here's how I solved it**:

The issue was from the command:

```
rails generate model Program name:string logo:json motto:text school_id:references
```

It is supposed to be `school:references` and not `school_id:references`, so during the migration Rails is unable to find the table `school_ids`.

So I modified the command to:

```
rails generate model Program name:string logo:json motto:text school:references
```

And it worked fine.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**