# PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation does not exist for Multitenant Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, rails-postgresql, apartment-gem

I am working on a Multi-tenant Ruby on Rails App along with another developer. I pulled his branch and received new migration files. I ran rake db:migrate. I visit the index of that controller and I get the undefined error.

After some research I understood that I ran migration after I created my Tenant. (Reference: [PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: relation "..." does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290250/pgundefinedtable-error-relation-does-not-exist?rq=1)) and I also understand that rake db:reset resolved this issue in development. But doing a reset purges my data which I am fine with in development.

My concern is, how does this work in production? When I release to production... does that mean that for existing tenants I cannot run migrations and ship new features?

Is there a permanent solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the following line in your config file,

```
config.tenant_names = lambda{ Customer.pluck(:tenant_name) }
```

When you run `rake db:migrate` all the existing tenant's schema will be migrated.

Comment: Thanks mate! Missed that inch of detail. Don't have enough points to upvote but surely deserves one.

Comment: I have up voted your question, so that you would have some points to up vote for answers to your later questions :-)